# what if we don't use '&' to iterate in range loop

Tags: c++, arrays

What if we don't use `&` after `int` or `auto`? Can we write the loop like

```
for(int i:a)// here a is an array
{
   ...
}
```

What would be the difference if we use `&` and if we won't.

Comment: We would make an extra copy.

Comment: If the loop modifies `i` it will only modify the local extra copy, and not modify the element in `a`.